# find all exec programs

Tags: c++, exec

I must simulate data stored on CD/DVD.

I have 3 classes:

1. CD contain something about movies
2. CD contain something about music
3. CD contain something about games

I must display, for each type of CD / DVD, applications installed on the computer, which
allow access to it (different player's for music/movie, or various games ex solitaire).

How can I find all that exe programs?
I use the next function (but it finds just in specified folder).

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
#include<fstream>
#include<dirent.h>

void listFile();

int main()
{
    listFile();
    return 0;
}
void listFile(){

    int l=0;
    DIR *pDIR;
    struct dirent *entry;
    if( pDIR=opendir("C:\\Users\\A\\Desktop") ){
        while(entry = readdir(pDIR)){
            if( strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") != 0 && strcmp(entry->d_name, "..") != 0 )
            {
                l=strlen(entry->d_name);
                if(entry->d_name[l-1]=='e')
                    if(entry->d_name[l-2]=='x')
                        if(entry->d_name[l-3]=='e')
                            if(entry->d_name[l-4]=='.')
                            {
                                string x;
                                x=entry->d_name;
                                cout<<x<<endl;
                            }
            }
        }
        closedir(pDIR);
    }
}
```

Comment: I doubt [tag:c++] is the right language/tool for doing this. But if you insist, you'd be better off using s.th. like the boost filesystem library.

Comment: This is my project for school. So... must be a way.

Comment: You'll need to check `entry` then, if it contains a further directory, and descend there recusively (a hint to achieve the latter, pass the directory path as parameter to your `listFile()` function). I'll leave the rest to you to figure out for **your** homework.

Answer (score 0):

You must use your OS API since the standard C++ library has no provisions for listing directory or folders and their contents.

Your basic algorithm is to do a "for each" on each folder:

1. For each folder in the directory, call the search function based on
   the folder (recursion).
2. For each file, get the file name, and check for the ".exe"
   extension.

I can't tell you which API to use since you didn't specify your platform, OS and compiler in your question (please edit your question with the information).